# Nrwl Storybook React Not Rending Images

Tags: reactjs, storybook, nrwl

I have a react project built with Nrwl. I just noticed that all the images in my components are not loading. I researched a bit tried different techniques but couldn't fix it. I have these files for example

**libs/src/lib/components/Nav/Nav.tsx**

```
import React, { FC, MouseEvent } from "react";
import NavStyled from "./Nav.style";

export const Nav: FC<NavProps> = ({ click }: NavProps) => {
  return (
    <NavStyled>
      <div className="nav__container">
        <a className="logo" href="/">
          <img src="../../assets/icons/logo.svg"/>
        </a>
      </div>
    </NavStyled>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

**libs/src/lib/components/Nav/Nav.stories.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";

export default {
  component: Nav,
  title: "Components/Nav"
};

export const defaultStory = () => <Nav />;
```

**libs/storybook/.storybook/webpack/config.js**

```
const rootWebpackConfig = require("../../../.storybook/webpack.config");
// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config = await rootWebpackConfig({ config, mode });

  config.resolve.extensions.push(".tsx");
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts");
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
    options: {
      presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ]
    }
  });
  return config;
};
```

**.storybook/webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.stories\.tsx?$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve("@storybook/source-loader"),
        options: { parser: "typescript" }
      }
    ],
    enforce: "pre"
  });
  return config;
};
```

and I run the storybook using

```
nx run storybook:storybok
```

Comment: Are you using any loader in your original webpack to load images?

Comment: I don't think so. But there another webpack file at the top root level. I just editted the answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to know that are you using any image loader in your top root level webpack file?

Comment: I don't think so. I have kept the default configurations

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using any image loader, you can try this loaded by adding this to your webpack config file.

```
    const svgToMiniDataURI = require('mini-svg-data-uri');
        const rootWebpackConfig = require("../../../.storybook/webpack.config");
// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config = await rootWebpackConfig({ config, mode });

  config.resolve.extensions.push(".tsx");
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts");
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
    options: {
      presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ]
    },
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: true,
      generator: content => svgToMiniDataURI(content.toString()),
    },
  });
  return config;
};
```

Comment: Should I replace this with the root webpack file?

Comment: I am getting 'ERR! Error: Rule can only have one result source (provided use and loaders) in {'

Comment: I've updated my answer. Don't change the .storybook/webpack.config.js, instead add the above piece of code in libs/storybook/.storybook/webpack/config.js

Comment: Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (44:4)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/server/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export const defaultStory = addSourceDecorator(() => {
|   return (
>     <div>

Comment: It's compiling with lots of warning. and giving an error on the browser.

Comment: Have you installed url-loader before running storybook as dev-dependency?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215567/discussion-between-missak-boyajian-and-mohit).

Comment: yeah I have that